# GAS Wialon Local Remote API: Retrieve login data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, remoteapi

Good day,

I have a Wialon Local server (GPS monitoring system) and am planning to update a shared Google sheet using time-driven installable triggers.

As per the [Wialon documentation](https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/local/remoteapi2004/codesamples/login), I am able to get the desired response when entering my API call in a browser.

However, in GAS, I am getting the below error when trying to retrieve data from the response.

API Call:

```
  let apiURL = `http://my.tracking.site.come/wialon/ajax.html?svc=token/login&params={"token":"5dce19710a5e26ab8b7b898XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFCEED7DC03BC48FF5F8"}`
  console.log(apiURL) // This URL works in a web browser as expected
  var resText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL).getContentText() // error is raised on this line
  console.log(resText)
```

The error:

```
11:48:27 AM Error   
Exception: Invalid argument: http://my.tracking.site.come/wialon/ajax.html?svc=token/login&params={"token":"5dce19710a5e26ab8b7b898XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFCEED7DC03BC48FF5F8"}
wialonLogin @ wialon.gs:20
```

Kindly advise what I am doing wrong here as I have very little experience with both GAS and Wialon Remote API ... will appreciate any assitance.

Thanks.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot open the URL of `https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/local/remoteapi2004/codesamples/login`, in your situation, as a simple modification, how about URL encoding to the values of `token/login` and `{"token":"5dce19710a5e26ab8b7b898XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFCEED7DC03BC48FF5F8"}`? But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tanaike, I just saw a similar question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755863/invalid-argument-with-urlfetch
and I can confirm that adding var urlEncoded = encodeURI(apiURL) has worked. I am getting the desired response. Sorry for the question ...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to encode the URL.

```
let apiURL = `http://my.tracking.site.come/wialon/ajax.html?svc=token/login&params={"token":"5dce19710a5e26ab8b7b898XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFCEED7DC03BC48FF5F8"}`
  console.log(apiURL) // This URL works in a web browser as expected
  var urlEncoded = encodeURI(apiURL);
  var resText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlEncoded).getContentText() // error is raised on this line
  console.log(resText)
```